# Can an adjective precede a determiner?

Tags: adjectives, determiners

> Start browsing our collection of **officially licensed the Beatles merchandise**.

For my job, I am required to write about various types of products. Recently, while I was writing about band merchandise, I stopped to think about adjectives and determiners. Most of the time, we place the adjective between the determiner and its noun; however, it wouldn't make sense to put 'officially licensed' after 'the' in 'the Beatles merchandise'.

Is this a very specific exception to the rule? Or should 'the' be removed?

Comment: Why do you say *it wouldn't make sense to put 'officially licensed' after 'the' in 'the Beatles merchandise'*? There's nothing wrong with [***the officially licensed merchandise***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+officially+licensed+merchandise%22) as used in many written contexts in that link. And there's nothing wrong with using "Beatles" (***without*** an article) as a "noun adjunct" to modify something like *We sell **Beatles memorabilia***.

Comment: Remember that we ask *What's your favourite **Beatles** song?* We *don't* ask *What's your favourite **The Beatles** song?*

Comment: For context, I work in SEO, which requires specific ordering of words and encourages me not to omit or split determiners. I decided to keep 'the' for this reason. I would say that we shouldn't put 'officially licensed' after 'the', as this places additional emphasis on the descriptor, which is incidental.

Comment: It sounds to me like this is more a matter of *programming* than actual use of "natural" English. It would look a bit less clumsy if you enclosed all your artist names in quotes (then you could "more validly" refer to ***the officially licensed "The Beatles" merchandise***) - but this isn't really a question relevant to learning English. *Some* "cataloguing" applications implement the general principle of moving any leading determiner to the end of an entry name, which would give you ***the officially licensed "Beatles, The" merchandise***, But like I say, this isn't real English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about programming and searchable table entries, not the normal use of English

Comment: I think you're right. I suppose I was trying to find out if I could get away with adhering to strict SEO practices while maintaining correct English. The irony of SEO is that most of our 'mistakes' are inserted because that is how the general population search online.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the question is relevant to learners even if the reason I wanted the information pertains to something else.

Comment: I suggest you go for my idea of enclosing artist names in quotes (if doing that for ***all*** of them looks too weird, perhaps you could only do it for names that start with a determiner). At least if you do it like that, your system would cope if your company wants to advertise their ["The The"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_The) merchandise. (Otherwise I can see *that* band is gonna give you a real headache! :)

Comment: ...I can't see it's relevant that you might have a determiner *before* the relevant noun phrase **"[bandname]" merchandise** - in your example, ***our*** is a determiner, but it makes no difference that I chose to refer to ***the** officially licensed "[bandname]" merchandise*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, a determiner generally goes first in a nominal phrase. This sentence is not an exception. In fact, the definite article is not required here, because "officially licensed Beatles merchandise" is not specific. The sentence should be:

> Start browsing our collection of officially licensed Beatles merchandise.

(By the way, a determiner ("our") is required before "collection" because that is specific.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The world of SEO is annoying, and it often forces me to sacrifice correctness to improve our sales. Ordinarily, I would adopt the same logic as you have, but I will have to forgo some common sense to appease my boss.

Comment: Yes, there is "correct" English, and then there is English that is appropriate for (or sometimes required by) its context. (As I'm sure is true for every language.)